# Swift 4: formatting Date using string

Tags: swift

I know this question might be asked a lot times, i've looked over SO and couldn't find my solution.

I have a pizza delivery app, i want the timing to be the exact same as i want, to avoid bad customer service..So for example when the user orders a pizza, I want to get their current date of purchase using string's **only**,

I want the Date to look like something like this `Jan 22, 2018, 11:10 AM`,

I tried the following ->

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm a" // problem
```

the problem is i receive nil instead of what i want, also please i want the old fashioned way not the `Swift 4` `components` way, thanks

Comment: You have shown how you setup the date formatter, but not how you do the conversion. `dateFormatter.string(from:)`does not return an optional, so where exactly do you get `nil`? –  A [mcve] would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dateFormat is wrong. below is correct format

```
MMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm a
```